# Make ActiveRecord append some SQL automaticly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, legacy-database

[*updating question to clarify*]

Can I create a model in Rails 3/3.1 and make ActiveRecord automatically use/append some joins I configured to that model?

Ex:

Use code like this:

```
  class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.base_query
        joins("join t05 on d04.t05_ukey = t05.ukey left join d03 on d04.d03_ukey = d03.ukey left join d16 on d04.d16_ukey = d16.ukey")
    end
  end

  Component.first      # under the hood is doing Component.base_query.first
  Component.where(...) # under the hood is doing Component.base_query.where
```

But ActiveRecord calls the method **base_query** under the hood without the need to explicitly call it. Just to make it more Rails-like.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide about active record querying with [Arel](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). There are a couple of really good railscasts (@railscasts.com) on the topic as well. And if you find yourself with ugly where clauses, etc, take a peek at the meta_where gem. I swear by these three things.

Comment: Found that I can create a method (ex: basic_query) and includes all those joins(...) but I have to call "Component.basic_query" everytime I have to query a Component. I want ActiveRecord to append all those joins (from the sql query I showed) everytime I use the Component model, even if I call Component.find(1).